# Allen & Heath Xone K2 MIDI device not available in QLCPlus while working in Mixxx

Tags: music, midi, dj

I am new to the MIDI protocol and I wonder why my Allen & Heath Xone K2 controller is detected and working (at least with some non-intuitive mapping) in Mixxx, while QLCPlus detects the device, but I cannot find a working configuration. Even the Channel Wizard remains blank even though the output of touched sliders is visible with `aseqdump -p <port from aseqdump -l>`

Is there something I have overlooked? (Arch Linux 6.2.9-arch1-1)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: To use the automatic mapping _"You must have an input plugin assigned to the current universe for this feature to work."_ - do you? [Ref](https://www.qlcplus.org/docs/html_en_EN/howto-input-profiles.html)

Comment: Sure, in the Inputs/Outputs tab it says XONE K2 MIDI 1 is assigned to my universe (1). Also, interestingly, the mapping assistant works fine with an AKAI Fire controller. The output in the terminal looks similar and it just works in QLC+, which proves me right configuration-wise. On the other hand, AKAI MPX8 does not work just like the XONE K2.

Answer (score 0):

I really do not know what caused the issue, but now, a few updates later, everything works as expected...

1. I still have my XONE K2 detected and enabled in the mapping tab
   [image]
2. Then, in the Profile tab, I created a new profile and added all the buttons/sliders/knobs/encoders using the channel wizard (note that you have to manually change the type of some)
   [image]
3. By default, the profile is getting saved at `~/.qlcplus/inputprofiles/`, so you can create a backup or simply paste my XONE:K2 [QLC+ mapping from Github](https://gist.github.com/F1iX/870dba6bbe31fdb791c1e568c6f14fc2) there (I did not take the time to rename the knobs though)
4. Also works quite nicely with the Mixxx Learning Wizard now (see [mapping on Github](https://gist.github.com/F1iX/0c502a05301fea8ad5fd29651475d665))